# Converter objeto da classe para String

Tags: php

Estou tentando exibir a consulta do banco, mas ao tentar exibir aparece o erro `Object of class TDataTable could not be converted to string.` e apontando o erro para o arquivo `frm_noticia.php`... O que devo fazer para consertar esse erro ?

`Obs:. Ordem de Processo (controller_noticia > view_noticia > frm_noticia)`

**controller_noticia.php**

```
function obterIdLink() {
        $sql = "SELECT MAX(noticia_id) FROM noticia";
        $result = $this->getConexao()->executeQuery($sql);

        if($result != null) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**view_noticia.php**

```
function obterIdLink() {
        return $this->getController()->obterIdLink();
}
```

**frm_noticia.php**

```
echo $view->obterIdLink();
```

**TDataTable.php**

```
class TDataTable {
    private $FRows  = array();

    function __construct ( $resource ) {
        switch(DB_TYPE){
            case "MYSQL":
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
                    $this->FRows[] = new TDataRow($row);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    function Rows() {
        return $this->FRows;
    }

    function RowCount() {
        return count($this->FRows);
    }

    function bind($object, $line) {
        throw new Exception("Nao implementado");
    }

    function getRow($pos) {
        return $this->FRows[$pos];
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está tentando dar um echo num resource que é o resultado da query no banco. Por isso o erro.

Comment: @DiegoF sou iniciante no PHP, não entendi direito o que você quer dizer... se não for muito incomodo você poderia me explicar melhor isso ?

Comment: Coloca o código de `executeQuery()`

Comment: @rray se você observar vc vai vê q ja existe no arq. **controller_noticia.php**

Comment: Esse framework tem manual? ele parece ter um fluxo bem estrito

Comment: @rray Na verdade não tem isso é um parte do código do projeto da empresa onde eu trabalho, e tipo o software é todo desorganizado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `frm_noticia.php` você esta dando echo no `result` do banco.
Deveria passar `mysql_fetch_assoc` para pegar o dado `result`.

Para entender melhor de um `var_dump($view->obterIdLink())`

Comment: E o pior que já fiz isso ! kkkk e aparece isso `object(TDataTable)#6 (1) { ["FRows":"TDataTable":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(TDataRow)#3 (1) { ["MAX(noticia_id)"]=> string(5) "15434" } } } `

Comment: O resultado esta no ´FRows´

Teu obterIdLink do view_noticia.php deve retornar apenas o MAX(noticia_id) e não o objeto TDataTable
Deve ter um get FRows

Comment: Mas tipo como eu faço pra exibir esse resultado ?

Comment: Você pode usar var_dump(get_class_methods ($objeto)); para saber quais métodos disponíveis

Uma dica bem legal é usar o kintphp uma ferramenta muito boa para dar dump em obejtos
http://raveren.github.io/kint/

Comment: `array(5) { [0]=> string(11) "__construct" [1]=> string(4) "Rows" [2]=> string(8) "RowCount" [3]=> string(4) "bind" [4]=> string(6) "getRow" } `

Comment: Exatamente, existe o getRow.
Agora se você percorre o caminho você chega no resultado.
$arrayResultado = $view->obterIdLink()->getRow(0) ;
$max = $arrayResultado['"MAX(noticia_id)'];

Acho que é isso XD

Comment: desculpa te incomodar de novo mas, esse cód. vai na view, controller ou no frm_noticia ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38970/discussion-between-ikaro-sales-and-willian).